# Django IntegrityError: Key is not present in table (but query of key works)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-testing

I have a strange problem with Django tests. The issue only occurs when I ran the test command `python3 manage.py test`.

Background information: I have a subscription model with a custom save method which sends info mails, create bills and lessons and more. After the subscription is saved into the database with the `super().save(using=using, *args, **kwargs)` command, the method `self.create_lessons()` get's called and this method causes the IntegrityError on creation of the lessons, saying that the subscription doesn't exists in the table.

To check if the subscription really doesn't exists in the subscription table I have added a query `s = Subscription.objects.get(id=self.id)` and printed it to the console `print(s)`. The query and the print command are working fine, but i still get the integrity error.

Whats really confusing, at least for me, is that the error only occurs when I run the `python3 manage.py test` command. When I run the webserver and create subscriptions with the admin panel or the shell everything is running like it should.

Even stranger is that the error disappears for a while (2-3 successful executions of the test command) when I make a change to the code which doesn't really matter. For example a comment or a database query.

I have added the traceback, the custom save method of the subcription model and the create_lessons method below. Just tell me if you need any further code or information. I hope you guys can help me with this issue and any hint or tip is really appreciated! I'm struggling with this issue for a long while now...

**Edit:**

I have found a workaround to avoid this issue. When I add the keep-database and the debug-mode option to the test command and run `python3 manage.py test -k --failfast -v 3 --debug-mode` than my tests are working always.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
sut_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
sut_1  | psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "main_lesson" violates foreign key constraint "main_lesson_subscription_id_41a5ca44_fk_main_subscription_id"
sut_1  | DETAIL:  Key (subscription_id)=(5) is not present in table "main_subscription".
sut_1  |
sut_1  |
sut_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
sut_1  |
sut_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
sut_1  |   File "/code/main/tests_commands.py", line 105, in setUp
sut_1  |     sub1 = Subscription.objects.create(first_lessons_date=date,
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
sut_1  |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
sut_1  |     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
sut_1  |   File "/code/main/models.py", line 431, in save
sut_1  |     self.create_lessons()
sut_1  |   File "/code/main/models.py", line 211, in create_lessons
sut_1  |     l.save(using='primary')
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 740, in save
sut_1  |     self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 777, in save_base
sut_1  |     updated = self._save_table(
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
sut_1  |     result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
sut_1  |     return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
sut_1  |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
sut_1  |     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1375, in execute_sql
sut_1  |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
sut_1  |     return super().execute(sql, params)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
sut_1  |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
sut_1  |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
sut_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
sut_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
sut_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
sut_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
sut_1  | django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "main_lesson" violates foreign key constraint "main_lesson_subscription_id_41a5ca44_fk_main_subscription_id"
sut_1  | DETAIL:  Key (subscription_id)=(5) is not present in table "main_subscription".
```

Custom save method of subscription model:

```
#Custom save function which includes creating the lessons of the 
#subscription
def save(self, using='primary', *args, **kwargs):
    #Marks the bill as paid if the bill already was paid in advance
    if self.billing_mode == '2':
        self.bill_paid = '1'
    #If lessons_outstanding isn't defined and isn't zero, the value 
    #will be equal to the amount of lessons.
    if not self.lessons_outstanding:
        if self.lessons_outstanding != 0:
            self.lessons_outstanding = self.contract.lessons_count

    #Sends info email
    if self.bexio_id == None and self.info_mail != '1':
        #Sends email to student
        subject = 'Neues Abo wurde erstellt'

        #If there is a bill, the text with a bill will be sent.
        #Elsewise there's only the text without the reference
        #to the bill. 
        first_lessons_date = self.first_lessons_date + timedelta(minutes=60)
        if self.billing_mode == '2':
            body_text = """Hallo {} {}

            {} {} hat soeben ein Abo mit Startdatum {} für Sie erstellt.

            Wir wünschen viel Spass im Unterricht und stehen bei Fragen gerne zur Verfügung.

            """.format(self.contract.student.first_name, 
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.teacher.last_name,
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

            body_html = """<p>Hallo {} {}</p><p></p><p>{} {} hat soeben
            ein Abo mit Startdatum {} für Sie erstellt.
            <p></p>
            <p>Wir wünschen viel Spass im Unterricht und stehen bei 
            Fragen gerne zur Verfügung.</p>

            """.format(self.contract.student.first_name, 
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.teacher.last_name,
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
        else:
            body_text = """Hallo {} {}

            {} {} hat soeben ein Abo mit Startdatum {} für Sie erstellt. Die Rechnung erhalten Sie in einem separaten Mail. Falls Sie die Zahlungsweise «Papierrechnung» bei uns hinterlegt haben, erhalten Sie die Rechnung per Post.

            Wir wünschen viel Spass im Unterricht und stehen bei Fragen gerne zur Verfügung.

            """.format(self.contract.student.first_name, 
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.teacher.last_name,
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

            body_html = """<p>Hallo {} {}</p><p></p><p>{} {} hat soeben
            ein Abo mit Startdatum {} für Sie erstellt. Die Rechnung
            erhalten Sie in einem separaten Mail. Falls Sie die
            Zahlungsweise «Papierrechnung» bei uns hinterlegt haben, 
            erhalten Sie die Rechnung per Post.</p>
            <p></p>
            <p>Wir wünschen viel Spass im Unterricht und stehen bei 
            Fragen gerne zur Verfügung.</p>

            """.format(self.contract.student.first_name, 
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.teacher.last_name,
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

        #If there is no student address an escalation will
        #be created, because the info email can't be send
        if not self.contract.student.address:
            rel = ('Student (' + str(self.contract.student.pipedrive_id) + 
                    '): ' + self.contract.student.first_name + ' ' + 
                    self.contract.student.last_name)
            create_escalation(type='E1', category='S', object=rel)

        else:
            email_to = [self.contract.student.address.email]
            send_mail(subject, body_text, body_html, email_to)

        #send email to teacher
        subject = 'Abo erstellt für {} {}'.format(self.contract.student.last_name,
                                                  self.contract.student.first_name)
        #If there is a bill, the text with a bill will be sent.
        #Elsewise there's only the text without
        if self.billing_mode == '2':
            body_text = """Hallo {}

            Es wurde folgendes Abo erstellt. Die Rechnung wurde bereits mit einem Gutschein beglichen:

            Schüler: {} {}
            Startdatum {}

            Für weitere Informationen logge dich mit deinem Login unter backend.school78.ch ein. Dort kannst du auch die erteilten Lektionen eintragen.

            Bei Fragen wende dich an dein School78 Team.
            """.format(self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.student.first_name, 
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

            body_html = """<p>Hallo {}</p>
            <p></p><p>Es wurde folgendes Abo erstellt. Die Rechnung wurde
            bereits mit einem Gutschein beglichen:</p>
            <p></p><p>Schüler: {} {}<br />Startdatum: {}</p>
            <p></p><p>Für weitere Informationen logge dich mit deinem Login
            unter <a href='https://backend.school78.ch'>backend.school78.ch</a>
            ein. Dort kannst du auch die erteilten Lektionen eintragen.</p><p></p><p>Bei Fragen 
            stehen wir dir gerne zur Verfügung.</P>""".format(self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.student.first_name, 
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
        else:
            body_text = """Hallo {}

            Die Rechnung für das folgende Abo wurde per Email versendet – bei Papierrechnung erfolgt der Versand in den nächsten drei Arbeitstagen:

            Schüler: {} {}
            Startdatum {}

            Für weitere Informationen logge dich mit deinem Login unter backend.school78.ch ein. Dort kannst du auch die erteilten Lektionen eintragen und sehen, ob das Abo bereits bezahlt ist oder nicht.

            Bei Fragen wende dich an dein School78 Team.
            """.format(self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.student.first_name, 
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

            body_html = """<p>Hallo {}</p>
            <p></p><p>Die Rechnung für das folgende Abo wurde per Email
            versendet – bei Papierrechnung erfolgt der Versand in den
            nächsten drei Arbeitstagen:</p>
            <p></p><p>Schüler: {} {}<br />Startdatum: {}</p>
            <p></p><p>Für weitere Informationen logge dich mit deinem Login
            unter <a href='https://backend.school78.ch'>backend.school78.ch</a>
            ein. Dort kannst du auch die erteilten Lektionen eintragen und sehen,
            ob das Abo bereits bezahlt ist oder nicht.</p><p></p><p>Bei Fragen 
            stehen wir dir gerne zur Verfügung.</P>""".format(self.contract.teacher.first_name,
            self.contract.student.last_name,
            self.contract.student.first_name, 
            first_lessons_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

        #If there is no teacher address an escalation will
        #be created, because the info email can't be send
        if not self.contract.teacher.address:
            rel = ('Teacher (' + str(self.contract.teacher.pipedrive_id) + 
                    '): ' + self.contract.teacher.first_name + ' ' + 
                    self.contract.teacher.last_name)
            create_escalation(type='E1', category='T', object=rel)

        else:
            email_to = [self.contract.teacher.address.email]
            send_mail(subject, body_text, body_html, email_to, teacher=True)
            self.info_mail = '1'

    #Saves the model        
    super().save(using=using, *args, **kwargs)

    s = Subscription.objects.get(id=self.id)
    print(s)

    #Creates lessons if they don't exist
    if self.lessons.count() == 0:
        self.create_lessons()

    #Creates bill if there is none 
    if self.bexio_id == None and self.bill_paid != '1':
        #If bill type is paper, an escalation will be created and the
        #office will send a bill manually
        if self.contract.bill_type == 'P':
            #Creates bill with customcommand
            args = [None, self.pk]
            opts = {}
            call_command('create_bill', *args, **opts)

        #If bill type is email, the bill will be created directly in
        #Bexio and will be sent...
        elif self.contract.bill_type == 'E': 
            #Creates bill with customcommand
            args = [None, self.pk]
            opts = {}
            call_command('create_bill', *args, **opts)
```

Create_lessons() - method:

```
#Creates the lessons related to the new subscription
    def create_lessons(self):
        s = Subscription.objects.get(id=self.id)
        print(s)
        for i in range(0, self.contract.lessons_count):
            if i == 0:
                l = Lesson(lessons_date=self.first_lessons_date, status='T', subscription=self)
                l.save(using='primary')
            else:
                l = Lesson(status='N', subscription=self)
                l.save(using='primary')
```

Comment: In my original post I have said that the error disappears for a while when I make a small change to the code. Here an example. First I have changed `s = Subscription.objects.get(id=self.id)` to `s = Subscription.objects.using('primary').get(id=self.id)` and I was able to execute the tests 3 times without error. Afterwards the tests stopped working again.

Comment: Than I have outcommented the print command. From `print(s)` to `#print(s)`. After this change I was able to execute the tests without error once. Afterwards the error returned.